# android-camera-server-died-and-camera-error-100

Tags: android, camera

I have a question that is follow up on [Android Camera Server Died and Camera ERROR 100](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8647628/android-camera-server-died-and-camera-error-100/9929683#9929683)

I am getting similar error in my code. This error comes in automated test in which we are running many applications randomly. After a very long time we see this error :

> E/Camera ( 2088): [Camera.java:570:handleMessage()] Error 100

In your message you have written that you have solved this issue, could you please tell what you did to resolve this issue?

Comment: What's up with the all the hyphens in the title?  There's a space character, you know.

Answer (score 8):

I got that error in emulator, solved by removing `camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder)` from `surfaceCreated()` and calling it only in `surfaceChanged()`.

I'm a newbie but I hope this helps.

Comment: exactly what i am finding, should be accepted ans !